# Apache Ignite .Net GetDataStreamer WithExpiryPolicy

Tags: c#, ignite

```
var cache = client.GetOrCreateCache<int, int>("test").WithExpiryPolicy(new ExpiryPolicy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), null, null));
using (var ldr = client.GetDataStreamer<int, int>("test"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        ldr.AddData(i, i);
    ldr.Flush();
}
```

I set the WithExpiryPolicy, but the data added by GetDataStreamer does not expire. Please tell me how to set the data to expire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WithExpiryPolicy` does not modify the underlying cache itself. Instead, it returns a new instance with the specified policies. This allows you to configure different policies on the same cache depending on some business logic.

At the same time, the DataStreamer is looking for a cache as it was created and doesn't care about `WithExpiryPolicy`. I'd suggest you configure the cache explicitly and re-run your example with the following configuration:

```
        var cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration
        {
            Name = name,
            ExpiryPolicyFactory = new ExpiryPolicyFactory(
                new ExpiryPolicy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), null, null))
        };
```